# Click link, show information in another section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have any examples, but I can only explain what I need.

I am trying to learn with jQuery, how to show information in another div when clicking on a link?

For example, I have One column for a list of links for dogs. When clicking on a specific dog, theres another column that shows information about it.

How can I do this with jQuery and how would the HTML look? Would the list of links be inside of list items, and the information of each "dog" be in a it's own container?

```
<ul>
   <li> Dog 1 </li>
   <li> Dog 2 </li>
</ul>

<div class="dog-info">
   <div> 
   <h2> Dog 1 </h2>
   <p> blah blah </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="dogs">
  <li>Beagle</li>
  <li>Lab</li>
</ul>

<div id="dogInfo">

</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('ul#dogs li').click(function () {
    $("#dogInfo").html("More info about " + $(this).text() + " goes here");
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you possibly post a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

## [Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7GUYy/)

Here's the html:

```
<a id="dog1" href="dog1.html">dog1</a> <div> About Dog 1 </div><br>
<a id="dog2" href="dog2.html">dog2</a> <div> About Dog 2 </div><br>
<a id="dog3" href="dog3.html">dog3</a> <div> About Dog 3 </div><br>
<a id="dog4" href="dog4.html">dog4</a> <div> About Dog 4 </div><br>
```

And js:

```
$(function() {
    $('a ~ div').hide();
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('a ~ div').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If I am right, this get's the div below the archor, right? The information would be in another column, apart from the links. I will update my question showing an example.